# Changing Connection String VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I found this in another answer

```
Sub UpdateQueryConnectionString(ConnectionString As String)
  Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
  Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
  Set cn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("database")
  Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
  oledbCn.Connection = ConnectionString
End Sub
```

I seem to be getting an error on `Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection`
Run time error 1004

I can output my current connection string like so

```
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Connections("database").ODBCConnection.Connection
```

but trying to assign it gives me the same runtime error 1004

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections("ID").ODBCConnection.Connection = "anything"
```

I am sure there is an easy way to simply change the connection string...

Note I created this using the connection wizard to connect to another workbook on my computer the connection type is Database Query. I am using Excel 2013, maybe this is a glitch in Excel 2013...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. What you need to do is append `ODBC;` to the beginning of your connection string otherwise it will give you a run time error.

Comment: hear those crickets?  I do. they're playing for me.